# Adding index on neo4j node property value

Tags: neo4j

I have imported freebase dump to neo4j.  But currently i am facing issue with get queries because of size of db. While import i just created node index and indexed **URI** property to index for each node. For each node i am adding multiple properties like label_en, type_content_type_en.

```
props.put(URI_PROPERTY, subject.stringValue());

Long subjectNode = db.createNode(props);

tmpIndex.put(subject.stringValue(), subjectNode);

nodeIndex.add(subjectNode, props);
```

Now my cypher queries are like this. Which are timing out. I am unable to add index on label_en property. Can anybody help?

```
match (n)-[r*0..1]->(a) where n.label_en=~'Hibernate.*' return n, a
```

**Update**

```
BatchInserter db = BatchInserters.inserter("ttl.db", config);
BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider(db);
BatchInserterIndex index = indexProvider.nodeIndex("ttlIndex", MapUtil.stringMap("type", "exact"));
```

**Question**: When i have added node in nodeindex i have added with property **URI**

```
props.put(URI_PROPERTY, subject.stringValue());
Long subjectNode = db.createNode(props);
nodeIndex.add(subjectNode, props);
```

Later in code i have added another property to node(Named as label_en). But I have not added or updated nodeindex. So as per my understanding lucene does not have label_en property indexed. My graph is already built so i am trying to add index on label_en property of my node because my query is on label_en.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample is missing how you created your index.  But I'm pretty sure what you're doing is using a legacy index, which is based on Apache Lucene.

Your Cypher query is using the regex operator `=~`.   That's not how you use a legacy index; this seems to be forcing cypher to ignore the legacy index, and have the java layer run that regex on every possible value of the `label_en` property.

Instead, with Cypher you should [use a START clause and use the legacy indexing query language](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-search.html#indexing-search-query).

For you, that would look something like this:

```
START n=node:my_index_name("label_en:Hibernate.*")
MATCH (n)-[r*0..1]->(a)
RETURN n, a;
```

Notice the string `label_en:Hibernate.*` - that's a Lucene query string that says to check that property name for that particular string.   Cypher/neo4j is not interpreting that; it's passing it through to Lucene.

Your code didn't provide the name of your index.  You'll have to change `my_index_name` above to whatever you named it when you created the legacy index.